# Career outside academia for biologist + cognitive scientist

Tags: career-path, biology, psychology

I would like to think of my options for a job outside academia and was hoping to get ideas from others. I feel I'm between fields:

- I studied biology as an undergrad; but never pipetted anything since.
- I did a PhD (and postdoc, with relatively good outcome) in cognitive science/experimental psychology (fMRI, EEG, consciousness, decision making); but I'm not a psychologist and would not be able to do anything clinical.
- I can program/script small things in a few languages; but I'm no programmer.
- I can do some statistics; but I'm no statistician.

I can think of:

- Data Scientist
- Teaching in some university with no strong research agenda
- Consultancy of some sort

I now live in Germany. Can anybody contribute with experience/resources for this 'inbetween' training? I feel I could exploit it as a benefit for an interdisciplinary job, I'm just not quite sure how.

Answer (score 1):

[User Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) design and testing might be up your alley. UX is often housed in cognitive science departments (when it's not in CS).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize that cognitive science! You're talking $$$$$$. You should try to find Hospitals or Specialty care places that deal with neuro.